# Devise authentication with ActionController::Metal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, devise, actioncontroller

I need to make an API with Devise authentication. API is better to implement with `ActionController::Metal` descendant, but Devise relies on `before_filter` method which is only defined in `ActionController::Base` descendants.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Simply include some helpers in your `ApplicationController`

Example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Metal
    include AbstractController::Callbacks # This adds before_filter
    include Devise::Controllers::Helpers # This adds current_user
    ...
end
```

Comment: I also had to include   ```include AbstractController::Helpers```